# Отчество «Кирилович» в «Вечерах на хуторе близ Диканьки»

Tags: орфография, ономастика

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему в следующем отрывке [у Гоголя](https://ilibrary.ru/text/1088/p.23/index.html) в отчестве "Кирилович" стоит одна "л"?

> Вот приехали ко мне гости: Захар **Кирилович** Чухопупенко, Степан Иванович Курочка, Тарас Иванович Смачненький, заседатель Харлампий **Кирилович** Хлоста...

Comment: Так во всех изданиях "Вечеров..." или только в одном?

Comment: М-м... Владимир, разве ТАК написано у Гоголя? _Вот приехали ко мне гости: Захар Кирилович Чухопупенко, Степан Иванович Курочка, Тарас Иванович Смачненький, заседатель Харлампий Кирилович Хлоста..._  Откуда же ж **Ивановия**?

Comment: Украинский вариант имени Кирилл: **Кирило** (из википедии).

Comment: Написание с одной **л** встречается часто в 19 веке и повсеместно — веком раньше. В более современных переизданиях зачастую исправляют на **лл**, но не всегда. А в украинском одна **л** до сих пор остаётся, это правда.

Answer (score 1):

Отчество *Кирилович* образовано или от украинского имени [Кирило](https://classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-russian-ukrainian-bigruuk-term-39733.htm), или от русского — **Кирила** (отсюда же возможна и одна "л" в фамилии *Кирилов*).

[Дмитрий Кирилович Кирилов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) (1837—1877) — русский химик (XIX век).

***Кирила Иванович**, богатый тульский помещик, владелец села Богучарово и окрестных деревень, умирал бездетным* (Б. Тарасов. А. С. Хомяков — мыслитель, поэт, публицист; о XVIII веке).

> **ЯВЛЕНИЕ II**
> *Те же и Настасья Кириловна с Ваничкой.*
> **Настасья Кириловна** (*подходя к руке Соломониды Платоновны*). Вот, бабушка, и я пришла... Ваничка, представься бабушке.
> [А. Писемский. Ипохондрик](https://books.google.ee/books?id=6t9LDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT59&lpg=PT59&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=uwMQZ9VXQg&sig=ACfU3U1vcxM3YGKdviZTZqWeQ6k_MXRn_A&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjksuW8q43yAhXvs4sKHWCeCS0Q6AEwD3oECBMQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&f=false) (XIX век)